# How to convert wikitext to html in PHP?

Tags: php, api, wikipedia

I make a search request from [Wikipedia API](http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) for getting wikitext (page content).

Response:

```
Moscow
{{About|the capital of Russia|other uses|Moscow (disambiguation)}} {{Redirect|Moscow         City|the commercial district in central Moscow|Moscow International Business Center}} {{Pp-move-indef}} {{Infobox Russian federal subject |en_name=Moscow |ru_name=Москва |image_skyline=Moscow collage new (2012) lite.jpg |image_caption='''Top''': [[St. Basil's Cathedral]], [[Spasskaya Tower|Spasskaya Clocktower]]
```

What advice?

Comment: If you need the HTML, why do you query the API for the wikitext instead of requesting the parsed HTML?

Comment: @Juhana What should be an inquiry?
Current code:`$place_name = 'moscow';
$this->wiki->action = 'query';
$this->wiki->redirects = '1';
$this->wiki->titles = $place_name;
$this->wiki->rvprop = 'content';
$this->wiki->prop = 'revisions';
$this->wiki->format = 'json';
        
$this->wiki->get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the HTML, you can directly query the API, like so:

> `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&prop=text&page=Moscow`

This will give you the raw HTML for that particular page, and you can parse it as you like.

For explanation on what each parameter does, refer to the [API documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).